# JPA ERROR: timetable_entity_tuesday relation does not exists

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating a school diary app using spring boot and faced with a small problem. When I try to add some data to database, JPA shows me such error:

```
ERROR: relation "timetable_entity_tuesday" does not exist
```

I don't know why it's happening, because I gave all the settings to my entity, where it should look for the table.

So here is my code.

**TimetableEntity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "timetables", schema = "working_schema")
public class TimetableEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Getter @Setter
    private long id;

    @Getter @Setter @ElementCollection
    private List<String> monday;

    @Getter @Setter @ElementCollection
    private List<String> tuesday;

    @Getter @Setter @ElementCollection
    private List<String> wednesday;

    @Getter @Setter @ElementCollection
    private List<String> thursday;

    @Getter @Setter @ElementCollection
    private List<String> friday;

    @Getter @Setter @ElementCollection
    private List<String> saturday;

    @Getter @Setter @ElementCollection
    private List<String> sunday;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "timetable")
    @Getter @Setter
    private ClassEntity schoolClass;

    public TimetableEntity() {
    }
}
```

**TimetableRepository**

```java
public interface TimetableRepository extends JpaRepository<TimetableEntity, Long> {
}
```

Method, which adds data to database, stored in service:

```java
public TimetableEntity addTimetable(TimetableAddModel timetableData) throws SubjectNotFoundException {
        TimetableEntity timetable = new TimetableEntity();
        timetable.setTuesday(Arrays.asList("math"));
        timetableRepo.save(timetable);
        return timetable;
}
```

And here' how hibernate makes queries:

```sql
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        timetable_entity_tuesday
        (timetable_entity_id, tuesday) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

It tries to add data to `timetable_entity`, although `timetables` table was given to entity.

Here's my database:

[image]

If you know what can be a problem, please tell me, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: In your opinion, where should `@ElementCollection private List<String> tuesday` be stored?

Comment: timetables_tuesday. I added the screen of my database to my question

Comment: nope, `@ElementCollection` is designed to store data in separate table. in your case (postgresql, I believe) you need to use another approach: https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-array-java-list/

Comment: You can do the same as what Andrey is suggesting with pure JPA by using a converter to serialize the List<String> to/from a String. This will keep your code provider independent (or at least, not depending on the types project - but it is nifty). Using your own converter though can give you control over the representation, which might allow querying over it and any special characters that might get into the list entries.

Answer (score 0):

JPA 2.0 @ElementCollection and @CollectionTable annotations allow to store a collection of Java types. Try to modify the mapping, adding the @CollectionTable annotation to your entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "working_schema")
public class Timetables {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Getter @Setter
    private long id;

    @Getter @Setter @ElementCollection @CollectionTable(name = "Monday")
    private List<String> monday = new ArrayList<>();

    @Getter @Setter @ElementCollection @CollectionTable(name = "Tuesday")
    private List<String> tuesday = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, hibernate query should be like
Hibernate:

```
insert into timetables (id, Monday, Tuesday) 
values (?, ?, ?);
```

I hope it helps!